# asp.net parse the array json using json.net

Tags: asp.net, json, json.net

I write this code:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string m_order;

    try
    {
        var jsonSerilizer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var jsonString = String.Empty;
        context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
        {
            jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
        }

        List<myClass> tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<myClass>>(jsonString);

        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Count(); i++)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"d:\status\LOL.txt", "tmp["+(i+1)+"].rid=" +tmp[i].r_id  + "\r\n", Encoding.UTF8);

        }
```

`myClass` is defined as:

```
public class myClass
{
    public int f_id{get; set; }
    public int r_id { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public int c_id { get; set; }
}
```

When I send the JSON string from the client to my server, my server goes to the HTTP Handler and returns the following JSON string, all as expected.

```
[
    {
        f_id:100,
        r_id:200,
        count:2,
        c_id=111
    },
    {
        f_id:120,
        r_id:200,
        count:1,
        c_id=111
    }
]
```

But when program hits this line:

```
List<myClass> tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<myClass>>(jsonString);
```

my server crashes with the following exception.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Invalid JavaScript property identifier character: =. Path '[0].count', line 2, position 32.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseUnquotedProperty()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseProperty()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseObject()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Portal.Get_O.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: It looks like your server is printing out `c_id=111` where it should be printing `c_id:111`. It's hard to say exactly why that's happening without knowing your server code, but I get the impression you aren't using JSON.net there, so you might want to look into that.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen thanks my friend for pay attention to my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json "c_id=111" string is invalid. The correct json should always be in key:value pair. Key value should be separated by colon (:).
    {
        f_id:100,
        r_id:200,
        count:2,
        **c_id=111**
    },
    {
        f_id:120,
        r_id:200,
        count:1,
        **c_id=111**
    }

The correct json should look like this:
    {
        f_id:100,
        r_id:200,
        count:2,
        **c_id:111**
    },
    {
        f_id:120,
        r_id:200,
        count:1,
        **c_id:111**
    }

So, just verify the data contained in "context.Request.InputStream". It might be helpful to analyze this issue.

Comment: Keys also need to be quoted in JSON.